# Кеширование

Tags: html, кэширование, форма

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите как сделать так чтобы после отправки формы на сайте если пользователь нажмет в браузере кнопку "назад" чтобы форма была не заполнена.

Comment: чистить форму в onload страницы?

Comment: @15828, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @KoVadim, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Как мне кажется, @15828  понимает, что это необходимо, но не знает как.

Comment: Я вроде это делал комментарием, но как оно стало ответом, я не знаю. Исправил сие недоразумение.

Автору вопроса - вообще то это фича браузеров, оставлять поля заполненные и это нормальное поведение. Но нужно смотреть более детально на Ваш код. Может там тонна кода, которая эти поля проставляет (например ещё и php код).

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/autocomplete